# Compile-time constants in Python

Tags: python, debugging

As far as I know, the Python byte-code compiler compiles the symbol `__debug__` to `True` or `False`, depending on the `-O` switch and the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable, and handles the resulting Boolean as a constant. This is very handy, since I can add debug code and disable it at no speed penalty when I choose to.

Is there a way to handle other global variables like that?  Maybe some command-line option?  I sometimes have experimental features, which I would like to enable like that, but don't want to pay the penalty of the `if` in a deep loop.